# What are the best practices regarding ThreadPool? Using Python multiprocessing API

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, task, threadpool

I hope this is not off topic.

I am writing a python script that has a heavy workload, so I decided to use the Python `multiprocessing` ThreadPool API.

I am using that in this way:

```
pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=max_threads)
pool.map(routine, args)
```

How can I estimate the maximum number of threads to use and the maximum number of tasks that I can submit to the pool?

Executed routine has to make `subprocess` calls to external script and filesystem operation such as `os.path.isfile()`, `os.stat()` and `os.remove()`.

Each thread executes the routine on a small part of data and shares nothing with other threads, so locks are not used.

I am testing it on a quadcore processor, but I have to deploy it in a mini cluster of several cores.

If is there anything I can add, comment below..

Thanks

Comment: I think it depends a lot on what you want to do, are the tasks going to be IO bound, how many processors you have, is it easy to divide the input and then combine it, etc. Be more specific if you want a practical advice.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to make it more specific..

Comment: Also, I would advise some experimenting with different number of tasks and while doing it measuring execution times and trying to see if the processes are IO or CPU bound.